# Vega-lite: the bar chart is too thin when x channel is a fieldT, how can align it better and adjust width or padding?

Tags: vega-lite

I am making some bar charts with vega-lite, using vega-lite-api; the raw data comes with a field called "month" with values like "2020/09" "2020/08" ... "2019/06" ...

the `fieldT` recognized it nicely, and I can apply a brush to select narrower time ranges; but then the bar charts don't look good, it seems always a fixed value of width, too thin and the spacing between is too wide,

but in this visual, what makes more sense is to make the bar aligned to center of a month, because the data on y axis is aggregated for the whole month, not of a single date (first date of the month);

So how can make these bars to cover since beginning of each month till end of the month, and just leave a little gap (like 5px between? like in the `fieldO` below)

[image: when the x channel is a fieldT, Temporal values]

if change x channel to use `fieldO` of Ordinal values instead, then the width is better to wanted, and it adapts width well when brush select changes; but the month labels would be left as is, not so good;

[image: when the x channel is a fieldO, Ordinal values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the feature you're looking for is the [Time Unit](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/timeunit.html). If you apply a timeUnit to a temporal encoding, it will cause the visual representation of the feature to fill the given timespan.

For example, here is some data similar to yours that uses a raw temporal encoding ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgtghgTg1iBcIBG0QBoQFMB2BjA9gCYCW2A5gqAB6UgBmxmANoQuPtgC4AW6InATwAOmNp0xgh+KBCYgAvhgG0GzVogBusgK6iMgkWwCO2iF2KcInYhtHzFIQlYi0tTXQGcEAbVBgOPGwATAAMAIwAnAD04Xxuughhin4BvIihkTFBcTqi8EHJ7FxpIBnRIQDMOe55SWgpxcHh5QAs1QnwLYX+jenNMQCs7XkA7N2pTZkhAGzDCBXjvaX9ISNznYuBfVMAHOvTmyVlMRHrO4eT0WEh69cX21dh62P1RVvLmWHZGPF5A-fLUIxJ4-XIIA6vHrvUJAkLfEC-BARAEwkIxKqgmoIc6QiZ9WFtTEdO64paowa3OoNaFwtEzdbI0k02FrIm1LpMo60mJ7NmJf6cpqw058+BhBaC-Fo663EIo7lhEEIsFiiHUrlAr63c4AXQcAHdiIQtgMQnKgA)):

```
{
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "month", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"month": "2019/01", "value": 1}, {"month": "2019/02", "value": 2}, {"month": "2019/03", "value": 1},
      {"month": "2019/04", "value": 4}, {"month": "2019/05", "value": 7}, {"month": "2019/06", "value": 3},
      {"month": "2019/07", "value": 4}, {"month": "2019/08", "value": 6}, {"month": "2019/09", "value": 8},
      {"month": "2019/10", "value": 10}, {"month": "2019/11", "value": 7}, {"month": "2019/12", "value": 5},
      {"month": "2020/01", "value": 6}, {"month": "2020/02", "value": 9}, {"month": "2020/03", "value": 8},
      {"month": "2020/04", "value": 10}, {"month": "2020/05", "value": 11}, {"month": "2020/06", "value": 9},
      {"month": "2020/07", "value": 14}, {"month": "2020/08", "value": 15}, {"month": "2020/09", "value": 13},
      {"month": "2020/10", "value": 10}, {"month": "2020/11", "value": 16}, {"month": "2020/12", "value": 18}
    ]
  },
  "width": 500
}
```

[image]

You can apply a `yearmonth` timeUnit to the x encoding like this:

```
  "x": {"field": "month", "type": "temporal", "timeUnit": "yearmonth"},
```

If you do so, the result looks like this ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgtghgTg1iBcIBG0QBoQFMB2BjA9gCYCW2A5gqAB6UgBmxmANoQuPtgC4AW6InATwAOmNp0xgh+KBCZ9OxMJgCq2YpzYDM0MBx4gAvhgG0GzVogBusgK6iMgkWwCONiF3UQFl0QaMhCLwhaayY7AGcEAG1QXS5eRAAmAAYARgBOAHo0vlC7BFSjWL0EkBSM7MTc21F4RKL2eLZyrOSAZmqw2sK0YqaktNaAFk78+CGGuP0BiuSAVlHagHZJkubB7IA2RYQ21f6yjeSlnfH96cPZgA5TzfPSluz006v79YrU5NPPt5ms1NSpxWvUaF0eqSqGDytTmv0OKWygKhNQQdxBUweyQRWNO6ThKWxHWRXQQr3RawG2JGxLGP3JBwJyWyCxp3R6fTBWKZyW2rIQePpnOxJz58FSE0FmOxN1FqVhkvW2Oesr2CspTM+32S+K5mQB3zRHKlGshIGhBVeAF1-AB3YiEaZzZLaoA)):

[image]